# how to divide pandas dataframe into different dataframes based on unique values from one column and itterate over that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe with three columns

The first column has 3 unique values I used the below code to create unique dataframes, However I am unable to iterate over that dataframe and not sure how to use that to iterate.

```
df = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx")

unique_groups = list(df.iloc[:,0].unique())    ### lets assume Unique values are 0,1,2
mtlist = []

for index, value in enumerate(unique_groups):
    globals()['df%s' % index] = df[df.iloc[:,0] == value]
    mtlist.append('df%s' % index)
print(mtlist)
```

O/P

```
['df0', 'df1', 'df2']
```

for example lets say I want to find out the length of the first unique dataframe
if I manually type the name of the DF I get the correct output

```
len(df0)

O/P
35
```

But I am trying to automate the code so technically I want to find the length and itterate over that dataframe normally as i would by typing the name.

What I'm looking for is
if I try the below code

```
len('df%s' % 0)
```

I want to get the actual length of the dataframe instead of the length of the string.
Could someone please guide me how to do this?

I have also tried to create a Dictionary using the below code but I cant figure out how to iterate over the dictionary when the DF columns are more than two, where key would be the unique group and the value containes the two columns in same line.

```
df = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx")

unique_groups = list(df["Assignment Group"].unique())
length_of_unique_groups = len(unique_groups)
mtlist = []

df_dict = {name: df.loc[df['Assignment Group'] == name] for name in unique_groups}
```

Can someone please provide a better solution?

**UPDATE**

```
SAMPLE DATA

Assignment_group    Description                         Document
Group A             Text to be updated on the ticket 1  doc1.pdf
Group B             Text to be updated on the ticket 2  doc2.pdf
Group A             Text to be updated on the ticket 3  doc3.pdf
Group B             Text to be updated on the ticket 4  doc4.pdf
Group A             Text to be updated on the ticket 5  doc5.pdf
Group B             Text to be updated on the ticket 6  doc6.pdf
Group C             Text to be updated on the ticket 7  doc7.pdf
Group C             Text to be updated on the ticket 8  doc8.pdf
```

Lets assume there are 100 rows of data

I'm trying to automate ServiceNow ticket creation with the above data.
So my end goal is GROUP A tickets should go to one group, however for each description an unique task has to be created, but we can club 10 task once and submit as one request so if I divide the df's into different df based on the Assignment_group it would be easier to iterate over(thats the only idea which i could think of)

For example lets say we have REQUEST001
within that request it will have multiple sub tasks such as STASK001,STASK002 ... STASK010.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is easily solved by `groupby`: one of the most useful tools in `pandas`. :

```
length_of_unique_groups = df.groupby('Assignment Group').size()
```

You can do all kind of operations (sum, count, std, etc) on your remaining columns, like getting the mean value of price for each group if that was a column.

Comment: My end goal is to iterate over the group generated, For example lets say 3 groups are created, Now I want to iterate over those groups one by one. Lets says I take the first group in that group I need to take the first row of data and update the same on a webpage and then come to second and so on. Could you please advise how can I do that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to get out of each group? Vectorizing is always better than iterating

Comment: In that case it's a bit more complicated. I'll need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to really help you.

Comment: I have update the sample date and the description of what i'm looking for in the main text. Hope that helps. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I think your question might be too broad for StackOverflow. It can be probably divided into several questions, so it's quite difficult to help you. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to try something like `len(eval('df%s' % 0))`

Comment: Awesome! That does give me the actual length of the DataFrame. could you advise how can i use the name of the df and iterate over that one by one?

My end goal is to iterate over the group generated, For example lets say a 3 groups are created, Now I want to iterate over those groups one by one. Lets says I take the first group in that group I need to take the first row of data and update the same on a webpage and then come to second and so on. Could you please advise how can I do that?

Comment: I'd apreciate if you upvote the answer :) Try `for df in mtlist:
    len(eval(mtlist))`

Comment: appreciate your help but length is not the only thing which I'm looking for, my main goal is to iterate over the grouped dataframe.

Comment: Try `for df in mtlist: len(eval(mtlist))`

Comment: Ivan, the df frame has multiple rows so I want to iterate over those rows one by one.
Sorry if i wasnt clear with my request. i understand the above for loop would give me the length of all the df's created. Lets say I take df0 now when I iterate over that take the data from first row update it on a webpage then come to second row and carry on till the end until three groups are done. Hope that explains.